# Stopping a c# system tray application in .net 3.5

Tags: system-tray

I have a .net 3.5 C# windows tray application that is installed using inno.  In the uninstall script I need to stop the application if it is running.  I've tried several methods - all unsucessfully.  Is there a standard way of doing this that I am ignorant of?

Simon

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Taskkill to kill the process. Read more about Taskkill here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx

Comment: Seems a little extreme; surely there must be a standard mechanism to do this.

Comment: System Tray / Notification Icon applications are just applications. You stop them the same way you'd stop any other application. In other words, there is no standard way. Either you implement something using IPC (sockets, semaphores, windows messages), or you kill the process.